# How to install *.sh ubuntu14

Tags: software-installation

I have setup file *.sh, I installed Ubuntu 14. I have tried terminal mode its not working. 
How to run GUI mode.

Please let me know the commands and any other samples

Comment: `chmod +x /path/to/your/*.sh` then `sh /path/to/your/*.sh`

Answer (score 0):

To run a **.sh** file you need to open the terminal, then **cd** into the directory where the **.sh** file is located and then type this into the terminal:

```
chmod +x name-of-your-file.sh
```

then just

```
sh name-of-your-file.sh
```

The output of the command will appear on screen, if you have any other issue, let me know ! :)

Comment: There is no need for `chmod +x` if you want to execute script by running `sh` with the script name a an argument

Comment: Using `sh` (which is the `dash` shell in Ubuntu) generically to run any shell script is not a good idea: it will fail if (for example) the script contains bash-specific features. It could even use a completely different shell such as `csh`.